# Angular controller is not working and it is disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could anyone tell me why "LogingController" is disabled? I can not use "LogingController".

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('home.controllers', ['home.services', 'ui.select', 'ngAnimate'])
        .controller('HomeController', HomeController)
        .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

    function HomeController ($scope) {
        $scope.authError = false;
    }

    function LoginController ($scope, $state, toaster, HomeServices) {
        $scope.submit = function(user) {
            $state.go('');
        };
    }

})();
```

Here is the screen shot

[image]

Comment: There is no screenshot...

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: What do you mean by LoginController is disabled?

Comment: You should add the HTML page of you app and clarify what means "LoginngController is disabled"

Comment: My HTML page is added correctly.  When I use HomeController then it is ok But LoginController is not working.

Comment: any errors on console?

Comment: syntaticcally speaking his code looks legit, you should debug and check if the controller is actually loaded, put a breakpoint inside it and follow the code step by step.

Comment: @Karim thanks. It works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you have not included [ui-router] in the module